# Where should standard library include be writen ? .c or .h file?

Tags: c, header-files

I have the simple following code :

mainc.c:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "hello.h"


    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      hello ();
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

hello.c:

```
    #include "hello.h"

    void hello (void)
    {
      printf ("Hello world!");
    }
```

hello.h:

```
    #ifndef _HELLO_H_
    #define _HELLO_H_
    #endif
```

I need to include stdio.h in hello to be able to access the printf() function.

Where should I include it ? In hello.c or hello.h ? Is there a best practice as both solutions seem to be correct ?

Comment: You include the header files where the are needed. If you need a structure or type or macro or function declaration in your header file then include the corresponding  header file in your header file. At least that's my *opinion*.

Comment: Also note that symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like `_HELLO_H_`) are *reserved*. You should not define (as macros or anything else) yourself.

Comment: In the current use case, the right way would be to include stdio.h in hello.c ?

Comment: For this simple example, yes. And don't forget to declare the `hello` function in the `hello.h` header file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Header files within your application should only include system headers which are required to declare further interfaces within the header.

For example -- if your header includes functions which take a `FILE *` as a parameter, it should `#include <stdio.h>`. If it declares a structure containing a `uint32_t`, it should `#include <stdint.h>`. And so on.

System headers which are only used within the implementation should be left to the `.c` file. Your header should not `#include <stdio.h>` simply because the implementation calls `printf()`, for example.